# VIM does not replace the word after the dot punctuation. How to change it?

Tags: vim

I have the following problem

This is text:

```
printf("sysname %s",ut.sysname);
```

I want to use vim to replace `sysname` line by line. I type the command in my gvim:

```
:s/sysname/version
```

I want to get the output like this:

```
printf("version %s",ut.version);
```

But I get the output like this:

```
printf("version %s",ut.sysname);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you're missing the `g` command that applies to all matches on current line, instead of only the first one:

```
:s/sysname/version/g
```

as a bonus:

```
:%s/sysname/version/g
```

will replace all occurences in current file, not only on the current line.

Answer (score 0):

To do it on one line

`:s/sysname/version/g`

You can also use the `qq` macro recorder before typing that in, and press `q` after, and then use `@q` to replay that on any other lines you want to replace that on. Or press `:` `up` to select old commands.

Or to do it on every single line:

`:%s/sysname/version/g`

However with replacing every line you should be careful. If there is a lot of text try making your replacements more specific.

I would do

`:%s/\(printf("\)sysname\(.*\)sysname/\1version\2version`